# How to have Multiple Elements for one section in c#

Tags: c#, app-config, element, sections

This is what I have in my app config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Database_Servers" type="Database_Servers.Database_Servers_Section, BMS Internal Database Restore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral "/>
    <section name="Server_Instances" type="Server_Instances.Server_Instances_Section, BMS Internal Database Restore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral "/>
  </configSections>
  <Server_Instances>
    <Server_Instance Server_Name="sql2005rs,sql2008r2,sql2008r2rs,sql2012rs,bmslondon01" />
  </Server_Instances>
  <Database_Servers>
    <Database_Server Server_Name="bmslondon01" Database_Name="Everest_Carlyle" Database_Backup_Location="D:\SQL Backups\Carlyle\Everest_Carlyle.bak" TradeDesk_Location="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Carlyle.mdf" TradeDesk_Log_Location="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Carlyle_log.ldf" />
    <Database_Server Server_Name="bmslondon01" Database_Name="Test_London" Database_Backup_Location="D:\SQL Backups\Carlyle\Everest_Carlyle.bak" TradeDesk_Location="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test_London.mdf" TradeDesk_Log_Location="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test_London_log.ldf" />
  </Database_Servers>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is what I have for the namespace Database_Servers

```
namespace Database_Servers
{
    public class Database_Servers_Section : ConfigurationSection
    {
        //Create Database Server Element.
        [ConfigurationProperty("Database_Server")]
        public DatabaseServerElement Database_Server
        {
            get
            {
                return (DatabaseServerElement)this["Database_Server"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["Database_Server"] = value;
            }
        }
        //Define "Database_Server" Element
        //With "Server_Name", "TradeDesk Location", "TradeDesk_Log Location", "Database_Backup_Location"
        public class DatabaseServerElement : ConfigurationElement
        {
            //Server_Name
            [ConfigurationProperty("Server_Name")]
            public string Server_Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return (String)this["Server_Name"];
                }
                set
                {
                    this["Server_Name"] = value;
                }
            }
            //TradeDesk Location
            [ConfigurationProperty("TradeDesk_Location")]
            public String TradeDesk_Location
            {
                get
                {
                    return (String)this["TradeDesk_Location"];
                }
                set
                {
                    this["TradeDesk_Location"] = value;
                }
            }
            //TradeDesk_Log Location
            [ConfigurationProperty("TradeDesk_Log_Location")]
            public String TradeDesk_Log_Location
            {
                get
                {
                    return (String)this["TradeDesk_Log_Location"];
                }
                set
                {
                    this["TradeDesk_Log_Location"] = value;
                }
            }

            //Database_Backup_Location
            [ConfigurationProperty("Database_Backup_Location")]
            public String Database_Backup_Location
            {
                get
                {
                    return (String)this["Database_Backup_Location"];
                }
                set
                {
                    this["Database_Backup_Location"] = value;
                }
            }

            //Database_Name
            [ConfigurationProperty("Database_Name")]
            public String Database_Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return (String)this["Database_Name"];
                }
                set
                {
                    this["Database_Name"] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run this

```
private void BtnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database_Servers.Database_Servers_Section Database_Server_Config = (Database_Servers.Database_Servers_Section)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Database_Servers");
    string ToSelectDBServer = Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.Database_Name;
    ToSelectDBServer.Where(Database_Name => Database_Name.Equals(DBName.Text)).Select(Database_Name => Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.Database_Name);
    string DB_Backup_Location = Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.Database_Backup_Location;
    DB_Backup_Location.Where(Database_Backup_Location => Database_Backup_Location.Equals(ToSelectDBServer)).Select(Database_Backup_Location => Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.Database_Backup_Location);
    string TradeDesk = Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.TradeDesk_Location;
    TradeDesk.Where(TradeDesk_Location => TradeDesk_Location.Equals(ToSelectDBServer)).Select(TradeDesk_Location => Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.TradeDesk_Location);
    string TradeDesk_Log = Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.TradeDesk_Log_Location;
    TradeDesk.Where(TradeDesk_Log_Location => TradeDesk_Log_Location.Equals(ToSelectDBServer)).Select(TradeDesk_log_Location => Database_Server_Config.Database_Server.TradeDesk_Log_Location);
    MessageBox.Show(ToSelectDBServer);
    MessageBox.Show(DB_Backup_Location);
    MessageBox.Show(TradeDesk);
    MessageBox.Show(TradeDesk_Log);
}
```

I get this error, The element  may only appear once in this section.
is there no way to have multiple

I was wondering if anyone could help.

- The Database_Servers is the configSection that is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty much guessing here as you didn't say which section it is having a problem with, but shouldn't `public DatabaseServerElement Database_Server` be a list (or array)? [App.config multiple custom section items](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c56abee0-4af0-4896-8f47-e6a0ad53f5ae/appconfig-multiple-custom-section-items) may have the answer.

Comment: Sorry Andrew I'm a little confused, are you saying when defining a class? Or were you saying should I not set it up in the same way I set up Server Instances, if that's the case I was wondering how to set it up the way I have set it up, as I know it's possible I''m just not sure where I've gone wrong.